# How to build a kivy application using buildozer and the latest kivy?

Tags: kivy

Using buildozer I have successfully built and run an Android application.
Buildozer uses kivy-stable (1.7)

How do I build a kivy application using the latest kivy 1.8 ?

I noticed at
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/recipes/kivy/recipe.sh the lines

```
VERSION_kivy=${VERSION_kivy:-stable}
URL_kivy=https://github.com/kivy/kivy/zipball/$VERSION_kivy/kivy-$VERSION_kivy.zip
```

Does this mean that only the kivy-stable version can be used with buildozer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I can't remember if buildozer has a switch to use kivy master (1.8 is unreleased), but you can certainly make it work. Here's a few instructions assuming your shell is something bash-like.

First, create your own local kivy repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git
```

Second, export the environment variable `P4A_kivy_DIR` to point at this directory. If this variable exists, python-for-android (including the one downloaded and used by buildozer) will use that directory to build kivy.

```
export P4A_kivy_DIR="$PWD/kivy$
echo $P4A_kivy_DIR
```

The second line should print out the directory of your newly cloned kivy.

You can then run buildozer. You might need to first delete the .buildozer file in your app dir, or more specifically some of the python-for-android components - easiest is just to do

```
rm -rf /path/to/your/app/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
```

After that, just run buildozer and the python-for-android component should use your copy of kivy master.

If you want this behaviour to automatically work every time, you could put the export line in your .bashrc or some other suitable shell setup file. If you don't do this, you'll need to run the export line every time you create or replace a .buildozer directory.

Comment: Thanks it works fine. Is it documented somewhere in the docs/wiki/faq ?

Answer (score 1):

Now (as on January, 2020) there is an easier option: just specify version in  `buildozer.spec`, e.g.:

```
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc1
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Colab!!!

go to this website: https://colab.research.google.com/

Step 1 : Create  a new Note Book

Step 2 : add a new code[image: in top left corner]

Step 3:add your main python file and kv file

[image]

Note: Make sure that your notebook is connected to runtime
[image]

Step 4:Copy and paste these codes in spreate code cells

```
!pip install buildozer
```

.

```
!pip install cython==0.29.19
```

.

```
!sudo apt-get install -y \
python3-pip \
build-essential \
git \
python3 \
python3-dev \
ffmpeg \
libsdl2-dev \
libsdl2-image-dev \
libsdl2-mixer-dev \
libsdl2-ttf-dev \
libportmidi-dev \
libswscale-dev \
libavformat-dev \
libavcodec-dev \
zlib1g-dev
```

.

```
!sudo apt-get install -y \
libgstreamer1.0 \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
```

.

```
!sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6
```

.

```
!sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

.

```
!buildozer init
```

.

Make sure to rename your python file as main.py
and also upload all the images used in the programe(if used)

navigate to builder.spec file

[image]

uncomment and comment these following lines

add `__version__ = 0.1` at the top of your main.py

Then

add these Code

```
!sudo apt install build-essential autoconf libtool
```

.

```
pip install --user -U colorama
```

.

```
pip install libtool
```

.

```
pip install testcase-automaker
```

.

```
pip install autoconf
```

**Finally**

add this code ...
This will build the apk

```
!buildozer -v android debug
```

**This Worked for me
Hope this will work for all**

Answer (score 0):

Basically - you specify build related things in your buildozer.spec file.
Detailed how to - available on project page:
https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#init-and-build-for-android

In buildozer.spec you can define:

Requirements needed to build/ compile your project like:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements =python3,kivy,kivymd==0.104.2,pillow==9.1.0,sqlite3
```

You shouldn't forget about Android permissions if needed for example:

```
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = 
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Last thing in the specs is to define architecture for compiled file. For example:

```
# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 30
```

And:

```
# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.archs = armeabi-v7a, x86
```

Then terminal command to buildozer to compile:

```
$ buildozer -v android debug
```

You will end up with *.apk file that can be used on physical device (copy to the device, grant permissions to the file on the physical device) or in Android emulator (i.e. GenyMotion -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-up-an-emulator-for-vscode/).

If any troubles in build or live debugging you can connect to the emulator with adb, like:

```
$ adb logcat YOUR_DEVICE_IP > log.txt
```