# Issues with Kivy 1.9.1 - would like to downgrade to 1.9.0 on ubuntu vm for testing, but how?

Tags: android, ubuntu, kivy

Since I have some problems with Dropdown and Spinner widgets if I build my app with buildozer on the prepared lubuntu vm, I would like to find out if this is somehow related to the new kivy version 1.9.1.

Before that I used to start my app via Kivy-Launcher (Kivy 1.9.0), which worked fine. But I needed support for cp850 in my app, that's why I changed to buildozer.

Anyway, my Buttons in all Dropdown and Spinner widgets are not responsive in the usual manner. Often they take the touch-input only after multiple attempts, which makes my app unusable.

Therefore I would like to test if a downgrade to Kivy 1.9.0 on that ubuntu vm would solve the problem. What would be the easiest way to do so?

As I'm not experienced in linux package management, I would appriciate a detailled instruction.
I noticed there is a Var `$P4A_kivy_DIR`, which could point to another Kivy-repository, but I don't know how to provide it [(see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19834753/5496168).

What I've tried so far: I extracted Kivy-1.9.0.tar.gz to a folder and set `$P4A_kivy_DIR` accordingly.
In the output of the build-process I see `$P4A_kivy_DIR is not empty, linking /home/kivy/Documents/kivy-1.9.0 dir instead of downloading`. But ...

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/kivy/Documents/apk_tutorial/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/waldi2/build.xml:18: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools/ant/build.xml:1: Premature end of file.
```

Indeed: that build.xml is empty.
Any ideas?

Comment: just do `requirements = kivy==1.9.0` in the `buildozer.spec` file

Comment: Yes, that's for sure the easiest and coolest way to do it! It works. Maybe you reformat your comment as answer?

Comment: By the way: my original problem is indeed related to the Kivy-version 1.9.1, it has now disappeared completely. But this is going to be another post ...

Comment: It turned out that my 1st attempt to downgrade failed mainly because of insufficient disk space, so maybe that way it would've been successful too. Didn't test it, because the solution of @fins is far more elegant.